# Adding an existing Java project in a Flutter project

Tags: java, flutter

I need to integrate a existing Java project into a Flutter project. I researched and found out a way to do it by method channel, but the Java project is already created, code is ready and very lengthy. Is there a way to do it easily?

I tried to integrate a Java project into Flutter project, but couldn't find any solution. I'm expecting to have a better answer to do it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the basic module via the *`method channel`* but are not able to call the whole project which was already developed in *`android-java`*

- To achieve this you have to make a project in *`flutter - dart`* you can use your existing logic of java in dart

Comment: hmm, that's gonna be a problem :(
but thankyou so much for your answer.